# Re-loading the controller after Navigation ( SAP UI 5)

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a UI5 Application with (JS View)  a  few pages & navigation between them.  I am  using  mutual `oModels` for transfering data ( For example I am choosing some item on 2. page and I am showing the choosen items on 3. page etc.)

My problem is  after navigation the `Controller` will be loaded only once.  And I can't update my Models which means my `View` won't show the latest  datas that I've added to oModel .

Is there anyway for me to handle this problem ? How can I manage to  reload my Controllers ( `onInit` lifecycle function etc. )

PS:  `oModel.refresh(true)` on navigation function doesn't do what I need-

If you need to see my code I can add the relevant part

Comment: Are you using "two way binding" on your model?

Comment: So the actual problem is that the updated data from the model is not displayed accordingly in the second view. In that case, yes, we need more information. Show us how the user would interact with your app with screenshots and **code** showcasing how your app is structured, how navigations are performed, how models get updated, etc.

Comment: apparently not, Jorge Martins answer works fine for me.

Comment: Sure, you can repeat some logic every time when the view is navigated. But then you're trying to solve the symptom, not the cause. You shouldn't have to repeat that logic in `onInit` so that the view displays the updated data. Something is wrong. Since it's unclear what your app exactly does in code, I was asking for more information to solve the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onInit` lifecycle function is only supposed to run once.
If your goal is to run some logic every time you enter one of your screens, you should implement a RoutePatternMatched event handler in your controllers.

Use `sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);` to get your router instance and call the function `attachRoutePatternMatched` to attach your event. You can look into https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.routing.Router for more details.